# python how do I pass a value from a list to a url

Tags: python

```
url_a = """http://some.url/"""
url_b = """http://some.url/'{}'/target"""

a= requests.get(url_a)
a_data = a.json()
a_id = [i['id'] for i in a_data]

b= requests.get(url_b.format(a_id[0]))
b_data = b.json()
print(b_data)
 {u'message': u"Unrecognized REST Request: GET/aps/2/resources/'%5C73d49684-dc10-4d6a-ae56-eb3816cd7064'%5C/subscriptions", u'error': u'APS::Util::Exception'}
type(a_data)
<type 'list'>
```

URL A has some data fetched in json format, that is represented as a list of dictionaries. I need to feed that value for key 'id' into URL B but I can't do it. It's sending it as  http://some.url/'12345'/target with quotes. If I escape the quotes it is still sending literal escapes to the API controller. 
If I don't use quotes it returns an empty result.

A valid result is there if it's passed as /aps/2/resources/12345/subscriptions however I can't figure out how to represent it in python.

Appreciate some assistance.  Thank you.

Comment: Use `url_b = """http://some.url/{}/target"""`?

Comment: If I do that the result is just an empty result. but if I run that query as it should run outside of python I do get actual result.

Comment: What do you mean? You've explicitly put quotes in your string, so I'm not sure why you are not expecting them to be there, and if you remove them, they shouldn't stay there...

Comment: Woops...sorry guys, looks like it was correct. just use without ' '

Comment: Humm  I don't use this syntax usually and I'm not sure you need the quotes on brackets. Have you tried the other syntax for string formatting?  url_b = 'http://some.url/%s/target' % a_id[0]

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s_data = s.json()
>>> print(s_data)
[]
>>> f = i_ids[0]
>>> print(f)
73d49684-dc10-4d6a-ae56-eb3816cd7064
>>> f = i_ids[1]
>>> print(f)
89c20244-331a-48c4-afea-3e23e72af768
>>> s = requests.get(s_url.format(i_ids[1]), verify=False) 
>>> s_data = s.json()
>>> print(s_data)
>>> len(s_data)
143
>>>
```

Guys sorry but yes I just had to remove the single quotes from {}

Thanks